# Get value from shared preference in remoteview

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, remoteview

I am having a widget and i want to set some value from settings activity.
I have saved values to shared pref using this code:

```
MainActivity.editor.putInt("selected_theme", 1);
            MainActivity.editor.commit();
```

And in remoteview class i have done like this in onUpdate method:

```
MainActivity.prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    MainActivity.editor = MainActivity.prefs.edit();

    int saved_value = MainActivity.prefs.getInt("selected_theme", 0);
    Log.d("ggg", "receiver: " + saved_value);
```

however it always gives me value **0**, which is default. I need to get integer value like **1,2,3....** from shared preference which have been done in Activity class.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Store your preference values at `Application level`

Comment: yup thats i have done. I have saved values in activity class.

Comment: You actually want to perform something based on user's input inside widget ?

Comment: no no... user will select pre defined color from settings activity and on selection done i have stored 1 for red, 2 for yellow and etc etc. now i want 1,2,etc in remoteview so that i can change background according to that.

Comment: Why would you use a Static Shared Preferences Object ? Aren't you using any utility classes for that ?

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani Nope... what should i do? Do i need to write a separate class for it?

Comment: Yes, I am providing you a basic template in some time as my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use `Utility Classes` for performing tasks such as Data persistance (Shared Preferences , Data Base, Serialisation, etc). 
Here i am providing you a basic Template:

**GenericUtility.class** :

```
package com.your.packagename;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class GenericUtility {

    public static int getIntFromSharedPrefsForKey(String key, Context context)
    {
        int selectedValue = 0;

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.your.packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        selectedValue = prefs.getInt(key, 0);

        return selectedValue;
    }

    public static boolean setIntToSharedPrefsForKey(String key, int value, Context context)
    {
        boolean savedSuccessfully = false;

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.your.packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        try
        {
            editor.putInt(key, value);
            editor.apply();
            savedSuccessfully = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            savedSuccessfully = false;
        }

        return savedSuccessfully;
    }

    public static String getStringFromSharedPrefsForKey(String key, Context context)
    {
        String selectedValue = "";

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.your.packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        selectedValue = prefs.getString(key, "");

        return selectedValue;
    }

    public static boolean setStringToSharedPrefsForKey(String key, String value, Context context)
    {
        boolean savedSuccessfully = false;

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.your.packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        try
        {
            editor.putString(key, value);
            editor.apply();
            savedSuccessfully = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            savedSuccessfully = false;
        }

        return savedSuccessfully;
    }
}
```

**Usage Example:**

*For Saving Data in Shared Preferences:*

```
GenericUtility.setIntToSharedPrefsForKey("selected_theme", 1, getApplicationContext());
```

OR

```
GenericUtility.setIntToSharedPrefsForKey("selected_theme", 1, MyActivity.this));
```

*For Retrieving Data From Shared Preferences:*

```
int selectedValue = GenericUtility.getIntFromSharedPrefsForKey("selected_theme", getApplicationContext());
```

OR

```
int selectedValue = GenericUtility.getIntFromSharedPrefsForKey("selected_theme", MyActivity.this);
```

I hope this helps.